# Android compose animation - infinite animation with repeat listener

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-animation

In my android compose project, I have an animation like this:

```
val infiniteTransition = rememberInfiniteTransition(label = "")

val x by infiniteTransition.animateFloat(
        initialValue = 0.5f, 
        targetValue = 0.0f, 
        animationSpec = infiniteRepeatable(
            animation = keyframes {
                durationMillis = cycleTime
                0.5f at 0 with xEasingOut
                1.0f at cycleTime / 4 with xEasingBack
                0.5f at cycleTime / 2 with xEasingOut
                0.0f at cycleTime * 3/4 with xEasingBack
                0.5f at cycleTime with xEasingOut
            },
            repeatMode = RepeatMode.Restart,
        ), 
        label = "x animation"
    )
```

which works well.

But now I would like to trigger some action every time the animation restarts. For simple animations like `animateFloatAsState` there is a lambda for the onCompleteListener, as in

```
val x: Float by animateFloatAsState(
    targetValue = xTarget,
    animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = xDuration, easing = xEasing),
    label = "x animation",
) {
    // onCompleteListener lambda
}
```

But I cannot find a similar lambda for infiniteTransition...

Is there a way to do this, or what is the best alternative approach?

Ps: at first I assumed the keyframes animationspec would ensure that x really did hit the corresponding values - which is why I started using keyframes (I assumed I could then test for eg x == 0). But it seems that keyframes does not do this (and testing like that is probably not the best idea anyway).

Answer (score 0):

You can do a combination of `LaunchedEffect` and a variable to track the animation cycle. Here's how you can achieve it:

```
var restartCount by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }

val infiniteTransition = rememberInfiniteTransition(label = "")

val x by infiniteTransition.animateFloat(
        initialValue = 0.5f, 
        targetValue = 0.0f, 
        animationSpec = infiniteRepeatable(
            animation = keyframes {
                durationMillis = cycleTime
                0.5f at 0 with xEasingOut
                1.0f at cycleTime / 4 with xEasingBack
                0.5f at cycleTime / 2 with xEasingOut
                0.0f at cycleTime * 3/4 with xEasingBack
                0.5f at cycleTime with xEasingOut
            },
            repeatMode = RepeatMode.Restart,
        ), 
        label = "x animation"
    )
// Use LaunchedEffect to detect animation restart
    LaunchedEffect(x) {
        restartCount++
        // You can perform your action here whenever the animation restarts
        // You can also use restartCount to keep track of the number of restarts.
        println("Animation restarted. Restart count: $restartCount")
    }
```

Comment: As far as I can see this doesn't work, since `val x by infiniteTransition ...` causes the composable its living in to recompose on each frame, and so LaunchedEffect is launched every frame - far too rapidly. Do you agree?